# CompletableFulture runAsync not starting new thread

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future, work-stealing

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
//somecode
System.out.println ("Do something")
}, Executors.newWorkStealingPool() );
```

I want to do something in async. But my code is never executed. It is not able to get thread to execute ?

Comment: Your task is executed in `ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1` thread.

Comment: You have to make sure your application does not exit before the asynchronous execution.

Comment: I am planning to use Executors.newCachedThreadPool() instead of  Executors.newWorkStealingPool() to prevent application from exiting

Comment: That’s one possibility. Another would be calling `join()` on the returned `CompletableFuture` before letting the main thread exit. Or, as any reasonable application should do, you keep a reference to the `ExecutorService` you created (regardless of which one) and call `shutdown()` at the end, to clean up. Then, after `shutdown()`, you can call `awaitTermination(…)` on the `ExecutorService` before the main thread exits.